# Mutate vuex store state with action within axios response - commit does not work

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

**Preamble**

I'm completely stumped by this. The answer will be obvious, of that I am sure, but I can't see it.

**The Problem:**

I cannot write to my vuex store with an Axios response. I have read about and tried async/await, thought I had a decent grasp of promises and have copied examples word for word. No dice.

This is my mutator, it works when passed a payload outside of axios:

```js
mutations: {
    setDays (state, payload) {
        state.savedDays = payload
    }
}
```

This action, created for debugging purposes, correctly updates the store with the word "cheese" and logs the expected response object to the console:

```js
getDays ({commit}) {
    axios.get('/days/')
    .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
    commit('setDays', "cheese")
}
```

This action does not update the store, but does still log correctly to the console:

```js
getDays ({commit}) {
    return axios.get('/days/')
    .then( (response) => {
        // response object removed for debugging
        commit('setDays', "cheese")
        console.log(response.data)
    }
})
```

I have read the Vuex docs and many other solutions on here, have tried many things, including the following (doesn't work):

```js
async getDays ({commit}) {
    const response = await axios.get('/days/')
    commit('setDays', response)
})
```

I receive no error messages, use chrome vue-devTools.
Thank you in advance.

---

Okay, I did this to further test based on comments below:

```js
async getDays ({commit}) {
    commit('setDays', "crackers")
    const response = await axios.get('/days/byType/30/1')
    console.log("Response:", response.data)
    commit('setDays', response.data)
    return response
}
```

When this action is dispatched, the store value is successfully mutated to "crackers".

console.log successfully logs the response object.

The second commit does nothing, even if I try and commit a string rather than the response.data object.

Comment: commit('setDays_', response). Is `setDays_` a type error?

Comment: I am not sure if you can commit multiple inside inside one action

Comment: Even if I remove the first one, the second one does not commit. There must be some underlying config issue. I will rebuild in a vanilla app from the vue-cli and go from there. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with your third and fourth code sample. `axios.get()` returns a promise. so you either have to use `async` `await` or `.then`.
To make your fourth example work, all you have to do is to commit `response.data`

```js
async getDays ({commit}) {
    const response = await axios.get('/days/')
    commit('setDays', response.data)
})
```

In order to return the value use the following lines

```js
async getDays ({commit}) {
    const response = await axios.get('/days/')
    commit('setDays', response.data)
    return response.data
})
```

---

FYI you could also use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const { data } = await axios.get('/days/')
commit('setDays', data)
return data
```

Comment: I think there is an underlying issue with axios. Using your method (which makes sense, thank you) I get: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".

Comment: Try to use the second code example (without object destructuring) and `console.log('Response:', response)` there you can check if `response.data` exists